# Simple shopping cart problem using session in PHP

Tags: php, session

i made simple PHP shoppingcart based on session. from bock "Build your own database driven web site using php & Mysql"

its contain 3 files: the controller **index.php**, and the two template files **catalog.html.php**, **cart.html.php**

the problem is when i click on "**View your cart**" link, the session will end and $_session['cart'] will unset automatically or something

sorry i cant explain it very will
so here is the codes:

**/* index.php - the controller*/**

```
$items = array(
 array('id' => '1', 'desc' => 'Candian-Australian Dictionary',
  'price' => 24.95),
 array('id' => '2', 'desc' => 'As-new parachute (never opened)',
  'price' => 1000),
 array('id' => '3', 'desc' => 'Songs of the Goldfish (2CD set)',
  'price' => 19.99),
 array('id' => '4', 'desc' => 'Simply JavaScript (SitePoint)',
  'price' => 39.95));

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Buy')
{
 // Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['cart'] array
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['id'];
 header('Location: .');
 exit();
}


if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Empty cart')
{
 // Empty the $_SESSION['cart'] array
 unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 header('Location: ?cart');
 exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['cart']))
{
 $cart = array();
 $total = 0;
 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id)
 {
  foreach ($items as $product)
  {
   if ($product['id'] == $id)
   {
    $cart[] = $product;
    $total += $product['price'];
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 include 'cart.html.php';
 exit();
}

include 'catalog.html.php';
?>
```

**/* catalog.html.php - display all product*/**

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
 '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>Product catalog</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charest=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your shopping cart contains <?php
 echo count($_SESSION['cart']); ?> items.</p>
<p><a href="?cart">View your cart</a></p>
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item Description</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php htmlout($item['desc']); ?></td>
    <td>
     $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
     <form action="" method="post">
      <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php
        htmlout($item['id']); ?>"/>
       <input type="submit" name="action" value="Buy"/>
      </div>
     </form>
    </td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
<p>All prices are in imaginary dollars.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**/* cart.html.php - display the products in the cart*/**

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .
 '/includes/helpers.inc.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>Shopping cart</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type"
content="text/html; charest=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>
<?php if (count($cart) > 0): ?>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Item Description</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td>Total:</td>
   <td>$<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($cart as $item): ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php htmlout($item['desc']); ?></td>
    <td>
     $<?php echo number_format($item['price'], 2); ?>
    </td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Your cart is empty!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<form action="?" method="post">
 <p>
  <a href="?">Continue shopping</a> or
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Empty cart"/>
 </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The typical problem here is that there is no valid location for the session data to be stored set in the php.ini file (or with session_save_path), or there a insufficient permissions to save the info.

If you are using a hosting company, make sure to check their wiki on where they want the path set to. Some require you to have a sessions folder in your root that you use.

If it is a localhost setup, make sure that the web server has write access to the save path.

Answer (score 0):

Is `register_globals` on? I see that you have a `'cart'` key in your session; you then set `$cart` to an empty array:

```
if (isset($_GET['cart']))
{
 $cart = array();
 $total = 0;
 foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id)
 {
   ...
```

If globals are registered in your php.ini, this could cause your cart to be overwritten when this code is executed. Either turn it off or use different names.

More info about [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Answer (score -1):

first of session_start() should go on top before anything else.

Comment: `session_start()` already appears before any output in the code above.

Comment: but still it's a good practice to keep it on top :-), and no one asked him to check on the page where he adds items in cart if there the session works fine or if at least something is added in the session...

Comment: @Bogdan Yet, this is rather a comment, other than an answer to the problem.